# Difference between Bayesian T-Test and Bayesian Informative Hypotheses Evaluation (BAIN) on JASP?

Tags: r, bayesian, t-test

I have three friends in an honours project and we are trying to perform a Bayesian Analysis.

I am doing a Welch’s T-Test due to very uneven group sizes, one is doing a linear regression and another is doing a one-way ANOVA. After performing these frequentist tests, we were hoping to also do a Bayesian analysis to get a better look into our data, and see what evidence we have for the null/alternative etc.

We cannot figure out how to do it on R, so we have downloaded JASP.

Under Bayesian T-Tests on JASP, there is no option for a “Welch’s T-Test.” However, I can do a BAIN analysis (Bayesian Informative Hypotheses Evaluation). The other two are able to do both, but get different ‘answers’ between the T-Test and the BAIN analysis.

We were wondering if there is a difference between what these two things are testing? We have trawled the internet to no avail! If there are differences, what is the better one to use post a null significance frequentist test?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this question should be posted on Cross Validatad ..

Comment: What does that mean @MrSmithGoesToWashington? Sorry I'm new to this!

Comment: [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is the place for rather theoritical and statistical questions .. here we are at the place for programming issues ..